# Why was my other account removed?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I need to know why I was removed, if it was because I didn't use this site much, well I couldn't - it wouldn't let me ask stuff for a month or even comment.

Can a moderator answer me? I lost over 30 reputation points on my other account.

Comment: What was your other account's name?

Comment: The league of unknown gamers, this is 2 questions in one cuz i am confused on how i lost rep when this one got removed when i didn't gain rep from it and y this one got removed

Answer (score 17):

Your account was removed because it was very clear it was a sockpuppet for another account.  This was reinforced by subsequent behaviour by the master account.

You can have more than one account on Arqade, so long as you don't use them to do what one cannot.  Things like (but not limited to):

- Using two to vote for each other
- Voting on the same post multiple times
- Using a secondary account to bypass rate limits

are all abuses of the system, and as a moderator, it is my job to take action when I find something like that happening.

In this instance, I did so by removing the lesser used account.

Comment: No i figured out what the rep was from, u r wrong, it was from upvoting other pples posts, and accepting answers and even so, it would have been transferring data since this one decided to break

Comment: Also is using alt. Accounts to ask a question when one has "exceeded question limit" against the rules (i have not seen rulebook yet and i don't know how to)

Comment: And this was lesser used because it broke, i waited the week for posting too often then it started over and i didn't even ask anything else after the 7 days so i guess i had to wait for this to get removed to do so, + don't u think an ENTIRE WEEK is too much i have school (i am a sophomore)

Comment: The account was deleted due to the activity between the accounts. The activity was just the deciding factor in which one went. It did not make what you were trying to do okay in any sense.  Additionally, your account didn't, "break"; it was rate limited due to the low quality content you were provided. Using a second account to bypass that will usually result in a suspension, along with secondary account deletion. I would highly recommend not doing so.

Comment: I didn't use the other one as a "sockpuppet" i voted on other pples posts and such fairly i wasn't "trying" to do anything i was using the other one bc this one broke and again, idk how on earth i lost rep when this one was removed when i didn't gain it from this one, also see how much i used the other one as well? .  How can u call it a sockpuppet? And this one was also the original i had no choice but to do this, bc this one broke, whereas i was unable to post stuff for OVER a week, so in a sense this kinda turned on you.....(that doesn't mean what u think it does "turned on you" it doesn't)

Comment: Because diamond moderators have access to tools that make it very clear you were (and still are) operating two accounts, and the voting between them was clearly sockpuppeting.  Like I said, two accounts themselves are fine, so long as they are not used to do what one account cannot. Currently, you're right on the edge of that usage. It's understandable that you want to get help, but you have to follow the rules to do so. It's our job to ensure those rules are upheld, so if we catch you circumventing the rules again, we're going to have to take action.

Comment: And read my other comments on this post thoroughly to get a better understanding

Comment: @UnknownTheAnonymous You're not making a good case for yourself by insulting people who are trying to help you and trying to convince us that you didn't use your accounts to vote for each other. Please try to be nicer, and don't try to cover yourself by saying you didn't do something you did.

Comment: I made a "private reply" to mods i want to take it back how do i delete?

Answer (score 5):

Frank explained why he, as an Aqrade mod, did what he did, but not everything you are angry about was his doing.

Your account exceeding the question limit had nothing to do with Frank, Arqade, or any human mods. It is an automatic feature after asking enough poorly received questions. When this happens, the solution is to either improve the questions you've asked, or wait. You can still interact with the site in every other respect (including posting answers, if you don't also hit the answer limit).

This is not something that can be manually resolved (even if someone wanted to make an exception for you). More information can be found in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited).

Actually, he may have done you a favour here- you managed to post this question so this seems to have gotten you out of the question ban.

Comment: I made a "private reply" to mods i want to take it back how do i delete?

Comment: @UnknownTheAnonymous You can't. Even if you could,  this wouldn't change the fact that they've probably already read it. This applies in real life too by the way- think before you send angry messages. What you do now is apologise.