# Why have I been banned from asking questions?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

The last question I asked was one year ago, and took forever but ended up with -5 votes. I then asked another one recently (not downvoted or upvoted) which got a couple of answers as well, literally no one had a problem with it.

Then I go to ask a third question (something to do with a Minecraft map I am making) and it tells me I have been blocked for 3 days because my posts have not been received very well by the community. "Take a breather, everyone learns at their own pace" etc.

But what caused this post ban?

Comment: *"The last question i Asked was one year ago"* - but then why on your profile it says *"Member for 36 days"*, also can not find any question with a -5 on your profile unless you deleted it (though i suspect you are using an alternate account since i can't imagine how you would have a 1 year old question on an account that's just a bit over a month old)

Comment: I thought it was, timing is NOT my strongsuit

Comment: @Howdoi.... FWIW, the rate limiting should be over now (for this instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That last question of yours at -5?  That wasn't a year ago.  It was last month.  [You can see it here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359159/defeating-skeletron)

Not even mods are privy to how the rate limiters work.  Nor can we lift them; it's meant to slow down low quality posts, so users don't run headlong into the *real* blocker: the question ban.  That ensures you only get to ask one question every six *months*.  It's hard to get into.  It's even harder to get *out* of.

Your second question was better received; maybe a little short on research, but the community didn't think it was a bad question.  From my observations (entirely guessing; no privileged information whatsoever), users usually get two questions before the rate limiters hit.  It looks like your first question hit enough of the negative indicators (downvoted, closed, deleted) that your second question would've had to have been something very positively received to avoid the rate limits.

So for now, all you can do is wait out the three days.  Once you ask another question, try to make sure it's a good one, and the rate limiter shouldn't kick in again.

Comment: They should make it so moderators can lift the ban if they feel the ban is not necessary.

Comment: That sounds like a great thing to have, @Howdoi...., but that would result in moderators being bombarded by users who feel they didn't deserve to be banned.  I'd much prefer to just let the system take care of it; we have enough to do as is.

Comment: Thats understandable but there is litterally this site of stack exchange that would make it a bit easier, but aren't there an abundant amount of moderators here? Idk their would be some sort of system in place, like where the ban is this long b4 a moderator can decide, well you know, i understand how annoying the bombarded thing would be, but again to what i was saying about the system to stop them from being able to have it lifted by a moderator if it's a week, i remember my friend told me about this one time he got banned for 1 week and it JUST ended so he went to ask a question to find he

Comment: Was banned for another week and it was 0 days and whatever, to me i thought it was cruel and unfair, and just wrong, but i don't exactly know how everything on the site works yet, so i can't really say anything on the matter

Comment: I honestly prefer reddit but at this point i decided it would be more efficient to ask my questions here AND there

Comment: We, as moderators, should not be making decisions on system imposed bans, @Howdoi....  It turns an objective algorithmic judgement into a subjective one, where consistency gets thrown out the window, and luck of the draw can play a part in who is able to continue posting.  Consistency is important.  There are standards here that every user must meet, and not doing so means not being able to post.  It's not cruel; it's just the system working as designed.

Comment: @Howdoi.... One other note I'd like to make is that your friend and yourself need to be careful with your interactions; we vote on content here, not who posted it.  If there's an indicator that you're voting based on who, instead of what, we're going to have to take action. For more information, see [this previous question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13592/)

Comment: From what i am seeing here that dude had serious anger issues, and i understand the reasoning (i almost misread it and got confused, almost)

Comment: Is it possible to have so much rep to where this rule is more lenient to the user who has that much rep?